# React Chart.js fetch data

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, fetch

just find an example with react and chart.js

https://codepen.io/createwithdata/pen/aXZVWX

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Roboto, sans-serif";

// Data generation
function getRandomArray(numItems) {
  // Create random array of objects
  let names = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  let data = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    data.push({
      label: names[i],
      value: Math.round(20 + 80 * Math.random())
    });
  }
  return data;
}

function getRandomDateArray(numItems) {
  // Create random array of objects (with date)
  let data = [];
  let baseTime = new Date('2018-05-01T00:00:00').getTime();
  let dayMs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  for(var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    data.push({
      time: new Date(baseTime + i * dayMs),
      value: Math.round(20 + 80 * Math.random())
    });
  }
  return data;
}

function getData() {
  let data = [];

  data.push({
    title: 'Visits',
    data: getRandomDateArray(150)
  });

  data.push({
    title: 'Categories',
    data: getRandomArray(20)
  });

  data.push({
    title: 'Categories',
    data: getRandomArray(10)
  });

  data.push({
    title: 'Data 4',
    data: getRandomArray(6)
  });

  return data;
}


// BarChart
class BarChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.myChart.data.labels = this.props.data.map(d => d.label);
    this.myChart.data.datasets[0].data = this.props.data.map(d => d.value);
    this.myChart.update();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myChart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, {
      type: 'bar',
      options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      data: {
        labels: this.props.data.map(d => d.label),
        datasets: [{
          label: this.props.title,
          data: this.props.data.map(d => d.value),
          backgroundColor: this.props.color
        }]
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} />
    );
  }
}


// LineChart
class LineChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.myChart.data.labels = this.props.data.map(d => d.time);
    this.myChart.data.datasets[0].data = this.props.data.map(d => d.value);
    this.myChart.update();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myChart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, {
      type: 'line',
      options: {
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'week'
              }
            }
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                min: 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      data: {
        labels: this.props.data.map(d => d.time),
        datasets: [{
          label: this.props.title,
          data: this.props.data.map(d => d.value),
          fill: 'none',
          backgroundColor: this.props.color,
          pointRadius: 2,
          borderColor: this.props.color,
          borderWidth: 1,
          lineTension: 0
        }]
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} />;
  }
}


// Doughnut
class DoughnutChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.myChart.data.labels = this.props.data.map(d => d.label);
    this.myChart.data.datasets[0].data = this.props.data.map(d => d.value);
    this.myChart.update();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myChart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: false
      },
      data: {
        labels: this.props.data.map(d => d.label),
        datasets: [{
          data: this.props.data.map(d => d.value),
          backgroundColor: this.props.colors
        }]
      }
    });

  }


  render() {
    return <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} />;
  }
}


// App
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: getData()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        data: getData()
      })
    }, 5000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="main chart-wrapper">
          <LineChart
            data={this.state.data[0].data}
            title={this.state.data[0].title}
            color="#3E517A"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="sub chart-wrapper">
          <BarChart
            data={this.state.data[1].data}
            title={this.state.data[1].title}
            color="#70CAD1"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="sub chart-wrapper">
          <BarChart
            data={this.state.data[2].data}
            title={this.state.data[2].title}
            color="#B08EA2"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="sub chart-wrapper">
          <DoughnutChart
            data={this.state.data[3].data}
            title={this.state.data[3].title}
            colors={['#a8e0ff', '#8ee3f5', '#70cad1', '#3e517a', '#b08ea2', '#BBB6DF']}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

on this example function `getData()` gets data from `getRandomArray()` and `getRandomDateArray()`

but how can I get data from some API?

I've got an error if I just put fetch to `getRandomArray()`

How to write fetch correctly, I want to `getData()` get updated data from fetch.

Should I create another class and use fetch in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Do you want any one chart from all of these or all ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I just want to understand hot to load data from JSON correctly

Comment: Ok, if it doesn't matter then you have to make the axios call and get the response and pass it to graph data

Comment: I understand, but when i add fetch to the getRandomArray it doesn't work :(